# Only single class file being added to jar

Tags: java, jar

I am trying to add two class files to .jar file. I am using the command:

```
jar cfve CashFlow.jar cashFlowCalculator cashFlowCalculator.class cashFlowCalculator$1.class
```

But this is only adding the cashFlowCalculator.class file, while ignoring the $1.class. There aren't even any errors, it's just never mentioned. It is not added to the .jar. Adding the $1.class manually seems to fix the issue of the program not running.

This is with Oracle JDK 8, if that is any help.

Comment: When using a command make sure the name of the file doesn't have special symbols or it properly quoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the jar command, but has everything to do with how the command line works. Basically, $1 is evaluated at the command line as "Var 1". So, as far as the jar command is aware, you are telling it to add "cashFlowCalculator.class" twice. Don't believe me? Run this on your command shell:

```
echo cashFlowCalculator.class cashFlowCalculator$1.class
```

and you will see

```
cashFlowCalculator.class cashFlowCalculator.class
```

Because $1 evaluates to "empty" as it is very likely undefined.

Instead, try this line for your jar command:

```
jar cfve CashFlow.jar cashFlowCalculator cashFlowCalculator.class cashFlowCalculator\$1.class
```

And that should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse, you can go File > Export > Java > Runnable Jar....and select the class with the main method.

Comment: Doesn't actually address OPs issue, which is that the jar command isn't adding both files to his jar. Once both files are there, it runs fine.